# Strange behaviour when integrating jQuery ajax with Wicket

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket

Im trying to combine jQuery ajax requests with Wicket but I am facing a small problem...

The requests works the first time but the second time it fails. The js console says that it occurs because of an syntax error, "unexpected token". Looking at the request with firedebug it looks correct the first time but the second time there is no response.

The first time the button is pressed both "onRequest" and "neforeRender" is called, the second time though ONLY "beforeRender" is called.

Im unsure if its jQuery or Wicket thats the villain here... The fact that "onBeforeRender" is called both tiems seems to indicate that the request is coming through, bvut at the same time "onRequest" isnt called the second time even though firedebug confirms that the data is sent...

Anyone here got a clue or theory on what the problem is?

Below is the jQuery code called on a "onClick" event on a submit button.

```
function getTestValue() 
{
var testArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
$.ajax({
    url : $('#mark').attr('json:callback.url'),
    type : 'post',
    cache : false,

    data : JSON.stringify(testArray),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(responseData) 
    {
        var values = responseData.sumPerTimeUnit;
        var labels = responseData.labels;
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        alert($('#mark').attr('json:callback.url'));
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
});
}
```

The panels "onBeforeRender" is called when the button is pressed, even if the request fails.

```
public class AbstractJSONHandlerPanel extends Panel
{
private static final long    serialVersionUID = 1L;

private AbstractJSONBehavior JSONBehavior;

private Form mMarkUp;

public AbstractJSONHandlerPanel(String id)
{
    super(id);

    JSONBehavior = new AbstractJSONBehavior();

    mMarkUp = new Form("markupid")
    {
        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
            super.onComponentTag(tag);
            tag.put("json:callback.url", JSONBehavior.getCallbackUrl());
        }
    };
    mMarkUp.setMarkupId("mark");

    add(JSONBehavior);

    Button n = new Button("dummyButton");
    n.add(AttributeModifier.replace("onclick", "getTestValue();"));

    mMarkUp.add(n);
    add(mMarkUp);
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeRender()
{
    System.out.println("BEFORE RENDER");

    String callbackUrl = JSONBehavior.getCallbackUrl().toString();
    mMarkUp.add(AttributeModifier.replace("json:callback.url", callbackUrl));

    super.onBeforeRender();
}
}
```

The "onRequest" is only called the first time the button is pressed.

```
public class AbstractJSONBehavior extends AbstractAjaxBehavior
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void onRequest()
{
    System.out.println("REQUEST");

    RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
    readRequestData(requestCycle);
    writeResponseData(requestCycle);
}

private void readRequestData(final RequestCycle requestCycle)
{
    WebRequest wr = (WebRequest) requestCycle.getRequest();

    HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest) wr.getContainerRequest();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = hsr.getReader();

        String jsonString = br.readLine();
        if( (jsonString == null) || jsonString.isEmpty() )
        {
            System.out.println(" no json found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(" json  is :" + jsonString);
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch( IOException ex )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private void writeResponseData(RequestCycle requestCycle)
{
    WebResponse wr = (WebResponse) requestCycle.getResponse();

    HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) wr
            .getContainerResponse();

    try
    {
        PrintWriter br = hsr.getWriter();

        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
        data.add(350);
        data.add(421);
        data.add(976);
        data.add(1521);
        data.add(432);
        data.add(121);

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>(6);
        labels.add("Jan");
        labels.add("Feb");
        labels.add("Mar");
        labels.add("Apr");
        labels.add("Maj");
        labels.add("Jun");

        StatisticsResponse resp = new StatisticsResponse(data, labels);

        Gson mGsonParser = new Gson();
        String json = mGsonParser.toJson(resp);

        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + json);

        br.write(json);

        br.flush();
        br.close();
    }
    catch( IOException ex )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How come ur using jquery and not the built in wicket stuff, e.g. calling ajax from javascript? Plus if you upgrade to wicket 1.6 it uses jquery for all its ajax stuff.

Comment: I'm jsute experimenting with combining javascript libraries with wicket, wanted to test if its possible to do it by manuella using jquery.

Comment: Also im using 1.5... Although form the looks of it I might just spare myself some trouble and use 1.6, seems like it would result in cleaner code aswell.

Comment: If its just a bit of experimenting i would checkout the wicketAjaxGet() function in the wicket-ajax.js and see what it does. Could maybe look at how the wicket guys did it in 1.5 and compare with 1.6.

Comment: Have you set jQuery.noConflict()?
 Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Dont invent the wheel again. Use wicket inbuilt ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that new Wicket 6 implementation does not work (ajax works only first time) if you have javascript exceptions. In my case it was AutoCompleteField which added js and it throws:

```
TypeError: obj is null
[Break On This Error]
objonkeydown=obj.onkeydown;
```

The full fragment of the wicket-autocomplete...js

```
function initialize(){
var isShowing = false;
// Remove the autocompletion menu if still present from
// a previous call. This is required to properly register
// the mouse event handler again (using the new stateful 'mouseactive'
// variable which just gets created)
var choiceDiv = document.getElementById(getMenuId());
if (choiceDiv !== null) {
isShowing = choiceDiv.showingAutocomplete;
choiceDiv.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(choiceDiv.parentNode);
}
var obj = Wicket.$(elementId);
initialElement = obj;
objonkeydown=obj.onkeydown;
```

I just remove it and it works now